# create complex report using crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

Here is what should comes in my crystal report:

1. there is some cases that each of them in addition to some info fields contains many children like:

   - persons: a list of person object each contain persons Info like name, family ...
   - bindings: a list of binding object each contain bindings Info like no, date , ...
   - ...
2. each case should comes in one page but whit all of its fields, persons and bindings list

The main problem is how to have a list which each object of list contains a nested list of one another object (note that each object of all lists contains some info fields).

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What do you have so far? Could you show a mockup/example of what you want and _precisely_ what you can't figure out?

Comment: an example: there is a list of employees. each employee have some basic information like name, family name, age, birth date... . in addition to this info fields each employee have a list of children that each children haves: name, age, sex ... , a list of his/her previous and current living place each living place have: city, street, alley, .... , and some other information lists. in other words there is a master object that contains some lists of detail object. I should display a list of master object with its detail lists one master object per page. what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

**Group Expert** is the way to do this. Add a grouping level for each stage in the hierarchy.